# Use jquery to grab data and populate html form

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql, drop-down-menu

Hi i need help grabbing data based on dropdown change . Basically selecting Item id from dropdown and then populating textboxes and other dropdowns with values from database. (other dropdowns are already populated and have assignment operators "<" , ">" , "=". I just want to have exact value selected in dropdown matching one from database.  Tricky part is some of the textboxes are hidden by default on page (using jquery) and only show when the appropriate dropdown value is selected. How do i accomplish this.

```
              <select name='Item' id='Item' >
            <option value='123'>123</option>
            <option value='124' >124</option>
            <option value='125' >125</option>
         </select>

<select name='oper' id='oper' >
        <option value='='>Equal</option>
        <option value='between' >Between</option>
        <option value='in' >In</option>
    </select>

<input id="CLEQ" name = "Clientequal" type="text" size="20" maxlength = "08" data-  bvalidator="digit,minlength[08],required">      
<input id="CLBE" name = "ClientBetween" type="text" size="20" maxlength = "08" data-bvalidator="digit,minlength[08],required">
<input id="CLIN"  name = "ClientIn" type="text" size="100" maxlength = "100" data-bvalidator="Client,required">
```

My jquery function to show hide the textboxes.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
        $("#CLEQ").show();
        $("#CLIN").hide();
        $("#CLBE").hide();   
$('#oper').change(function() {
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();

    if(selectedValue  === '=') {
        $("#CLEQ").show();
        $("#CLIN").hide();
        $("#CLBE").hide();
    } else if (selectedValue === 'between') {
       $("#CLEQ").show();
        $("#CLIN").hide();
        $("#CLBE").show();
    } else {
       $("#CLEQ").hide();
        $("#CLIN").show();
        $("#CLBE").hide();
    }
});



});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add all the relevant code and tell exactly where you're stuck. Unfortunately people can't guess what your actual problem is.

Comment: sorry i was in process of editing the code

Comment: You've got the right start with the change() function. The next step would be using .$ajax to call your server-side code.

Comment: but this is separate change code. I want to setup on top of the page which reads items change n populates textboxes accordingly .can u give me sample code for that please. just using sql select * from table where item = item1.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so found answer for this used json_encode to grab array and parsed through it to repopulate the html form. Thanks for help guys